# Sending coordinates via socket but messages are sometimes batched together, how to prevent this?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, air

I have an AIR server receiving messages. I have Flash client apps that are sending messages. Right now I'm just testing with a single client. I'm afraid that this issue might get worse when I have two clients sending coordinates...haven't tested it out yet.

I'm sending the mouse coordinates of the client as a series of String messages e.g. "100,200" and then parsing it on the server side. When the user is moving the mouse on the client, I'm sending lots of these message in quick succession to the server.

Most of the time on the server when I read the message, I get a single x,y...which is great. Sometimes when I'm reading the message the coordinates are batched together...

So if I'm sending (in quick succession)

"100,200"

"123,456"

"111,222"

When the server reads it I'll see

"100,200123,456111,222"!

Here's the code on the client side:

```
socket.writeUTFBytes( coordString ); //an x,y pair
socket.flush(); //make sure it's sent
```

How to I prevent this? Is it because I'm sending messages in quick succession?

**NB**
The suggestions for potentially sending via a different format are good. At this point, I'm just trying to keep it simple. The messages are mostly mouse coordinates as the user drags their mouse on the client. Every once in awhile there is a status message. All messages are really short...e.g. "GREEN", "RED", etc. I could potentially also send Integers and that will reduce the number of bytes that I'm sending. String "100" is 3 bytes, but I think as an Integer it might take 2 byes...so I'm saving a byte there. At this point, I don't see any lag on the server when it receives the mouse coords and moves something on the server's screen. I might go to sending bytes if it becomes an issue.

For those of you that have found this question and are sending more complex messages, perhaps AMF, JSON, XML would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that sockets are used, this is the effect you desire: Chaining messages keeps the communication overhead to a minimum.  You will have to "package" each message to keep them distinguishable.  If you have more than one message type and need to keep a clean separation, you could wrap each individual message in an XML node, or use JSON notation, for example.

But if you're only going to use the coordinates, adding a simple separator like `;` or a space or line break should be enough:

```
100,200;123,456;111,222; 

100,200 123,456 111,222

100,200
123,456
111,222
```

On the server side, you'll have to add code to split the received string by that character and process each individual result, of course.  I'd probably go for the line breaks - they improve readability for debugging.

Comment: Keeping it simple is good. I think for the amount of data that I'm sending, wrapping messages in XML or JSON would cause too much over head. But it's a good suggestion for more complex data on my future projects. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is you are overrunning your sends instead of waiting for one to be complete before send the next. Basically you are adding to the buffer before it is emptied.

So to fix this you have 2 options.
The first would be to make sure you are already not sending data before sending more. Kind of like batching them up in an array or something.
This method would not be all that great because on the server side it shouldn't matter what the client does. No matter what the client send the server should be able to handle it.

Now the second option would be to correct both the client and the server.
First on the client you need to end every send to the server with a null character. This is normally the standard as it would tell the server that this is the end of this round of data.

```
socket.writeUTFBytes( coordString + String.fromCharCode(0) );
```

And on the server side you will need to look for that null character so you know when a full data packet was recieved.

Comment: +1 for terminating coords with another character and info about overrunning the sends. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string presentation of a number to send numbers... that's redundant. Also, you may want to read on CRC (cyclic redundancy check) if that be the case. Other posters suggested using existing encoding formats - this is, in general a good way to go, however, XML, JSON or CVS are all very bad formats for transferring data over the wire. CVS is probably best for the simplistic task you are after, but it's still redundant.

If you can be sure of the size of the numbers you are going to send (are they all integers, of fixed size, bytes? shorts? doubles?) you could simply write one integer after another, never worrying about missing ones or confusion since you will be always reading the exact same length of bytes from the socket. There are also techniques to unambiguously write a variable length integers to a stream w/o the need of separators (one commonly used in Flash is UI29).

However, if you are planning on sending other kinds of data - take a look at AMF format. This format has been specifically designed to support ECMAScript data structures, and, unlike JSON it serves the purpose fairly well (JSON cannot represent many to many relations, cyclical structures, and it had actually messed up the strings format somewhat, on top of that, it is too verbose).
Even if the language you've chosen to write the server doesn't have an AMF library, it is really simple to write, but most industry-level languages have some implementation of AMF, so that should hardly be a problem.

Comment: +1 for suggestions of sending numbers instead of string representations.